# Are some survival waves inevitable in Saints Row: The Third?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I want to complete the game while saving certain things for last. About two or three times now, despite diligence, I've somehow completed 2/26 survival waves when I've never actually saved having completed any instance of survival waves. Theory: Is/are there any story mission(s) that count(s) as survival for the completion of the 26 survival waves? If not, how am I completing survival waves?
By diligence, I mean that I've restarted from progress 0.

I play with others. That's how I achieve my goal. I leave undone the first mission so that any missions that I complete beyond that in the story sequence, other than the automatic second and third ones, can be skipped. Other things that I am leaving undone include gang operations, stunt jumps, barn-storms, assassinations, vehicle thefts, highlighting of new list items, health, combat, and damage upgrades, and collection of sex dolls, money pallets, and drug packages. Many of these things can be reverted by loading an older save while remaining in someone's game, but gang operations cannot be reverted without rejoining the game. Survival waves are similarly...inconducive in that progress of them cannot be checked unless completed. Perhaps they suffer from a super-problem similar to gang operations.

I've checked the Saints Row Wiki article listing all of the survival waves, but didn't interpret any as associated with a mission, which is my best guess as to what I'm completing that may also complete the 2/26 survival waves.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed the same thing: I have never finished a survival wave, and yet I have 2/26 at the end of the game.

Here are my theories-

The mission at Murder Brawl should be considered a survival wave.  You have to survive several waves of Luchadores, right?  Maybe that counted.

I think the zombie mission is a survival wave, too.  You have to sit there and kill wave after wave of zombies, so I think that counts.

Other than those two missions, I can only see one other reason why we both ended up with 2/26 survival waves completed: There are waves of bad guys through the game and it eventually added up to surviving two whole rounds.  I know, I know...these are silly reasons, but I love the game and it's just weird that it happened to both of us!

Comment: I like your theories.

Comment: This doesn't seem too far off base. There was a ramp during a mission that counted as a stunt jump in Saints Row 2, and that was the only way to access it.